# Get List of All Managed Beans in JSF at runtime

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

I'd like to get a list of all managed beans in a JSF application.  In Spring, I can do something like [context.getBeansOfType()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3228823/80286).  Is there a corresponding method in JSF?

I have a number of `@ManagedProperty` beans that implement an interface. I'd like to get a list of these adapters and loop through them rather than invoke each bean explicitly in order to keep the code clean.

Thank you

Comment: What's the motivation for this, or just curiosity?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza i'll update the question to clarify

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with `BeanManager` class from `com.sun.faces.mgbean` package:

```
ApplicationAssociate application = ApplicationAssociate.getInstance(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext());
BeanManager beanManager = application.getBeanManager();
Map<String, BeanBuilder> beanMap = beanManager.getRegisteredBeans();
Set<Entry<String, BeanBuilder>>beanEntries = beanMap.entrySet();

for (Entry<String, BeanBuilder> bean: beanEntries) {
  String beanName = bean.getKey();
  if (beanManager.isManaged(beanName)) {
    BeanBuilder builder = bean.getValue();
    System.out.println("Bean name: " + beanName);
    System.out.println("Bean class: " + builder.getBeanClass());
    System.out.println("Bean scope: " + builder.getScope());
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** This is tightly coupled with Mojarra JSF implementation and doesn't work on other implementations.

Comment: Note: this answer assumes that you're using Mojarra and have it in compile time classpath. This won't work in other JSF implementations nor compile against the JSF API.

Comment: @partlov, thanks but i am not using Mojarra.  looking for something generic.

Comment: i'm awarding this the answer even though i'm not using Mojarra, because it provides the real answer to my question.. that it can't be done natively in JSF.

Answer (score 1):

If your beans are already in the session you can try the code below:

```
Map<String, Object> sessionMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
for (Entry<String, Object> beanEntry : sessionMap.entrySet()) {
    String beanName = beanEntry.getKey();
    Object bean = beanEntry.getValue();
    //TODO do something with bean, i.e. check if it's implements your interface and store into list
}
```

By saying that a bean is in the session I mean that the bean is already created and used in another object in the same session.

Comment: Warning: this approach works only when you use the legacy bean management facility, which was more than one year ago deprecated in favor of CDI. When using CDI, this approach doesn't work at all.