# Null when calling managed bean via @ManagedBean

Tags: java, jsf-2

I have two managed beans in session scopes. First one is a simple list of elements.

```
@ManagedBean (name = TrainList.BEAN_NAME)
@SessionScoped
public class TrainList extends ListBasic<TrainObj> {    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String BEAN_NAME = "trainList";

    public TrainList ()  {
        super();
    }
}
```

Second represents details information for particullar record from list and is called after user click record from first list.

```
@ManagedBean (name = TrainForm.BEAN_NAME)
@SessionScoped
public class TrainForm extends TrainObj {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TrainForm.class.getName());
    public static final String BEAN_NAME = "trainForm";

    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{trainList}")
    private TrainList trainList; /* + getter and setter */


    public TrainForm ()  {
        super();
    }

    public void refreshList(){
     if (trainList != null) {
            logger.debug(" trainlist is not null");
             trainList.refreshList();
        }
        else {
            logger.debug(" trainlist is NULL");
        }
}
```

So list bean is initialised before second. 
But still gets null when accessing first bean from second??

```
[2014-11-12 13:18] DEBUG [http-apr-8080-exec-7] - com.kropla.TrainForm.update(TrainForm.java:xx) - trainlist is NULL
```

What is wrong?

[please do not down-vote - I have searched an answer but haven't found proper/suitable answer]

I can list all of the managed bean (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15503044/2303190) and this bean is on list. But why I get null?

Comment: try with eager true in @ManagedBean

Comment: Still null. It looks like this class have never been created as a bean. But in oder classes (with the similar architecture) it works OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the problem was related with the way of initialization (calling) the second bean from first.

```
private String returnDetailPageName(TrainObj entityObj) {
        Map session = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap();
        TrainForm formBean = new TrainForm();
        formBean.setMe(entityObj); //setter for the entity vproperties
        session.put(formBeanName , formBean);
        return "goProdTraining"; //go to detail page
    }
```

This "session" way of calling bean was creating new bean which wasn't stored in JSF.
Changing the calling bean property by ManagedProperty do the trick with PostConstruct assign the parent bean to child bean (to prevent cyclic loop):

```
@ManagedBean (name = TrainList.BEAN_NAME)
@SessionScoped
public class TrainList extends ListBasic<TrainObj> {    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public static final String BEAN_NAME = "trainList";

    public TrainList ()  { super();}

    @ManagedProperty (value = "#{trainForm}")
    private TrainForm trainForm; //with getter&setter

    @PostConstruct
    private void setChildBeanProperty(){
        this.trainForm.setTrainList(this);
    }
}


@ManagedBean (name = TrainForm.BEAN_NAME)
@SessionScoped
public class TrainForm extends TrainObj {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TrainForm.class.getName());
    public static final String BEAN_NAME = "trainForm";

    private TrainList trainList; /* + getter and setter */

    public TrainForm ()  {
        super();
    }

    public void refreshList(){
     if (trainList != null) {
            logger.debug(" trainlist is not null");
             trainList.refreshList();
        }
        else {
            logger.debug(" trainlist is NULL");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to get bean like this. I have used below code in my application its working but am using  @ViewScoped yours is SessionScoped, try this it may work.

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
TrainList trainList = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{trainList}",TrainList.class);
```

Comment: I'm working on Tomcat and don't want to include another jar as a dependency (el-api.jar)