# Spring - Lookup implementation class

Tags: java, spring

I have (may be a simple question). I'm a spring starter and I'm looking for a solution for a simple problem.

I have a parser interface, and I want to collect all implementations of that interface to build a  Map.

My target is, to have a Factory class which is given a File and the Factory will give me the correct ParserImplementation for the filetype of the file.

I've never done something like this before and I'm struggling with finding some good results on Google.

Did anybody have some short hints or links how to start?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3228376/get-all-beans-implementing-a-generic-interface-in-spring

Comment: context.getBeansOfType() should be useful in this case

Comment: You would be better off using Spring's ServiceLocatorFactoryBean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<bean id="FactoryBean" class="com.exampleFactory">
    <property name="map">
        <map>
            <entry key="file1" value="com.example.ClassForFile1" />
            <entry key="file2" value="com.example.ClassForFile2" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Bound to a FactoryBean like this:

```
public class FactoryBean {

    private Map<String, String> map;

    public Map<String, String> getMap() {
        return map;
    }

    public void setMap(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

}
```

Comment: mhh yeah looks good to me, may just with teh change of <entry key="pdf" value="com.example.PDFParserClass"> <entry key="docx" value="com.example.DOCXParserClass">
and so on. is it possible to search >automatic< for that classes which than have a variable which contains the filetype for that parser. like public class TEST {static String fileExtension = "PDF"; ... } ?